# ormlite update not null field

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I want update only not null field. I have some class like below

```
@DatabaseTable
public class ClickCount implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6582623980712135028L;

    public static final String DATE_FIELD_NAME = "lastClickDate";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = DATE_FIELD_NAME)
    private Date lastClickDate;

    @DatabaseField(index = true)
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField
    private String description;

    @DatabaseField
    private int value;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
    private ClickGroup group;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ClickGroup getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(ClickGroup group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Date getLastClickDate() {
        return lastClickDate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * This updates the value and adjusts the date.
     */
    public void changeValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.lastClickDate = new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + value;
    }
}
```

I get some json and parse with ClickCount class, but some field may be null. When I update data in DB null field writing into DB. How write only not null field?

Updating data below

```
Dao<ClickCount, Integer> dao = getHelper().getClickDao();
ClickCount clickCountInDb = dao.queryForAll().get(0);
ClickCount clickCountFromServer = getFromServer();
clickCountFromServer.setId(clickCountInDb.getId());
dao.update(clickCountFromServer);
```

Comment: Sorry to come so late to this question.  I'm not quite understanding it.  Are you asking how to set fields to null?  Can you edit your question to explain what you need more?

Answer (score 0):

You have update each field manually after checking if its null or not. After that just update your fetched entity like this:

```
Dao<ClickCount, Integer> dao = getHelper().getClickDao();
ClickCount clickCountFromServer = getFromServer();
ClickCount clickCountInDb = dao.queryForId(clickCountInDb.getId());  // query for specific item. After this you should check if the query was succesful.
if (clickCountFromServer.getLastClickDate() != null)
{
     clickCountInDb.setLastClickDate(clickCountFromServer.getLastClickDate());
}
if (clickCountFromServer.getName() != null)
{
     clickCountInDb.setName(clickCountFromServer.getName());
}
// and so on for all fields

// after you set not null properties on the object clickCountInDb you have to propagate changes back to the database:
dao.update(clickCountInDb);
```